# OpenCV shows wrong or modified result when load image

Tags: python, image, image-processing, opencv

I have a graph of line which is made from photoshop when i load image using opencv in python using below code which give me Result 1 which is not match with actual image,

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
im = cv2.imread('5.png')
cv2.imshow('image', im)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: Result Shown in OpenCV python]

I load image to any image viewer its show me below Image which is actual image look like.

[image: Actual Image Should look like]

Comment: can you attach 5.png?

Comment: @learner Please find Below link .. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mTfUW7GUZkwxa3wrsUM8vI7WdGF19HJR/view?usp=sharing

Comment: transparency. Use `cv2.imread("5.png", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)` instead

Comment: @learner I tried before but still give me same result...no changes..

Comment: the problem is not with `cv2.imread`, it is with `cv2.imshow`. `cv2.imread("5.png", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)` this provides an array of shape `(1281, 1466, 4)` which specifies that there are 4 channels, 4th one being the transparency channel. while showing it though, it can't handle transparency

Answer (score 0):

PNG supports 4 channels image. The image 5.png has 4 channels like R G B and Alpha. Alpha channel is the transparency channel which defines the background for web designing. Anyway, you only need the first 3 channels RGB.
A small script below will work

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('5.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)    #this gives the 4 channel image

mask = image[:,:,3] == 0 #we find all the places where background is transperent

image[mask] = [255, 255, 255, 255]   #we replace that transperent background with white 
                                      #background

BGR = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2BGR)  #convert it to 3 channel

cv2.imshow('BGR',BGR)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```